# Grabbing int from object[][] array Java Reflect

Tags: java, arrays, object, reflection

I need to grab a int from a object[][], but have no idea how to do it with reflection.

I used this method to grab it from an object[]

```
    public static Object getInterfaceObject(String clazz, String field, Object obj, int index) {
    try {
        Client client = Boot.client;
        ClassLoader cl = client.classLoader;
        Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(clazz);
        Field f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object arr = f.get(client.getClient());
        return (Object) Array.get(arr, index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;


}
```

Since this next one is object[][], I don't know how to go about it.

I want to basically be able to do

```
getInterfaceObject()[arg1][arg2].otherStuff();
```

Comment: Be aware that if the array is really an `Object[][]`, then it **cannot** contain an `int`.  You need to retrieve an `Integer` and extract the wrapped value.

Answer (score 1):

You can downcast the **Object** to **Object[][]** like this:

```
((Object[][]) getInterfaceObject())[arg1][arg2].otherStuff();
```

Or do that inside **getInterfaceObject**:

```
public static Object[][] getInterfaceObject(String clazz, String field, Object obj, int index) {
    try {
        Client client = Boot.client;
        ClassLoader cl = client.classLoader;
        Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(clazz);
        Field f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object arr = f.get(client.getClient());
        return (Object[][]) Array.get(arr, index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And leave your callsite as you desired:

```
getInterfaceObject()[arg1][arg2].otherStuff();
```

A few of my opinions on clean code (take or leave of course):

1. Prefer **throw new RuntimeException(e);** to **e.printStackTrace();** (alter the IDE template)
2. Prefer explicit code to reflection. Reflection loses type safety.
3. Prefer specific types to **Object**